# Eigenvalue expansion of Green's function of non self-adjoint operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, greens-function

I have a general non-self adjoint operator $L$, and a set of equations with some inhomogeneous boundary conditions,

$$
Lq= 0 \quad in \quad \Omega,
$$

$$
q = q_0 \quad on \quad \partial\Omega.
$$

I am studying the sensitivity of the solution with respect to the boundary conditions. I have been using Lagrangian approach, but I would really like to get some physical insight on how the boundary condition affects the state $q$.

I know that the Green's function is essentially an operator that provides such information. However, since this is a numerical study, my guess would be to present the Green's function in terms of basis functions:
$$
G(x,x') = \sum \frac{q_n(x) q_n(x')}{\lambda_n}.
$$

What happens if the original operator is non self-adjoint? In fact, it is $\textit{almost}$ self-adjoint, i.e. is self-adjoint up to a linear transformation of the state vector $q$.

Can I do some kind of eigenvalue decomposition of the original and the adjoint problems to present the Green's function as a sum of basis functions product?